# Mocking Request.Url

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nunit

My controller using following line to assign url to the session

```
this.Session["MyUrl"] = Request.Url.ToString();
```

on unit test project side I setup controller like this

```
var fakeHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(t => t.HttpContext).Returns(fakeHttpContext.Object);
this.controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;            
controllerContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Url).Returns(new Uri("/Home/Details", UriKind.Relative));
```

on this last line I'm trying to setup `Request.Url` in order to pass the value I expect on the controller side.

All I'm getting as a result on `Request.Url` is `'/Home/Details'`.

Do I need to mock whole `Url` object inside request in order to get this to work?

Update:
I setup session object in httpcontext setup

```
fakeHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Session["MyUrl"]).Returns("/Home/Details");
```

but still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: You specified `/Home/Details` in your mock. What value do you expect to get in the controller?

Comment: I expect /Home/Details on the controller side also.

Comment: Isn't what you are getting?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm getting but still I'm getting 
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object e exception. My guess is that Request.Url.OriginalString is populated and all other Request.Url fields return exceptions.

Comment: Try providing an absolute url in your mock: `new Uri("http://example.com/Home/Details")`.

Comment: I'm not in position to use absolute url cause of production environment.

Comment: I don't get it. In your real code, when hosted in a webserver, Request.Url will always be an absolute url. I don't understand why in your mock you are providing a relative url and what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I tried with absolute url, same behaviour. I tried also to use on controller side   this.Session["MyUrl"] = Request.Url.OriginalString; yet again same exception.

Comment: You are getting a NRE, because of `this.Session`, not because of the url. Have you mocked the Session object anywhere? I can't see this in your code.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestion. Session object is mocked now but I still have the same exception. Any sugg.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be properly mocking the ControllerContext. Try this:

```
// arrange
var controller = new HomeController();
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
context.Setup(x => x.Request.Url).Returns(new Uri("/Home/Details", UriKind.Relative));
context.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(session.Object);
var requestContext = new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData());
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);

// act
var actual = controller.Index();

// assert
session.VerifySet(x => x["MyUrl"] = "/Home/Details");
...
```